# Почему не работает jsonp?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Не получаю ответа от сервера, в консоли только warning Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin 
Собственно вот код

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'www.mrsoft.by/data.json',
    cache: false,
    dataType : "jsonp",

success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $('.res').text(data);
}
}); 
});
```

Пробовал по разному, в ответ тишина, в чем может быть трабла?

Comment: В том, что вы не имеете права получать ответ от этого сервера

Comment: это косяк сервера?

Comment: Это косяк ваш, потому что вы не попросили у разработчика сервера разрешения на получение ответа. А если сайт принадлежит вам и разработчик это вы... ну, тоже ваш косяк, читайте что такое CORS :)